# Best place to put the code in the textbox event

Tags: vb.net

I have a code placed in a textbox got focus event.what it does is when it gets a focus it finds a value from a table and assigns it to the textbox.But if ther's no value it tells the user to define it and puts the focus on another control if the response is yes otherwise telling the user it can't proceed.

What i'm getting is,if there's no value and the response is yes it can't put the focus to that control and just loops the message.Any idea to break the loop if the response is yes.

```
    qry = "SELECT * FROM [fuel_allowance] WHERE [project number]='" & projcode & "' AND [employee number]='" & empcode & "'" & _
            "AND [current month]=(SELECT [current month] FROM [fuel_allowance] WHERE [project number]='" & projcode & "' AND" & _
            "[employee number]='" & empcode & "' AND MONTH([current month])=" & currentdate.Month & " AND YEAR([current month])=" & _
            "" & currentdate.Year & ")"
    If Button5.Tag = "New" Then
        Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = GetData(qry)
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            Do While dr.Read
                TextBox32.Text = dr.Item("total")
                If Val(TextBox32.Text) > 800 Then
                    TextBox37.Text = Val(TextBox32.Text) - 800
                Else
                    TextBox37.Text = 0
                End If
                TextBox38.Text = Val(TextBox36.Text) + Val(TextBox37.Text)
                TextBox31.Text = (Val(TextBox33.Text) + Val(TextBox32.Text)) * Val(TextBox34.Text)
            Loop

        Else
            If MsgBox("Fuel allowance not defined for the current month of " & MonthName(currentdate.Month, False) & vbCrLf & _
                    "Do you want to define it?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Project Payroll") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                If TextBox32.Focused = True Then
                    TextBox27.Focus()
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Cannot define allowance without defining fuel allowance", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Project Payroll")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: It's possible that you're referring to the wrong control. Please give your textboxes and buttons meaningful names instead of "TextBox32" etc. Then step through your code and see if the logic of what you're doing is correct, remembering that when you .Focus() a control then its .GotFocus() handler is called almost immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a rather common problem with the GotFocus event. What you are missing here, together with everyone else who makes this mistake, is that TextBox1 fires the GotFocus event again as soon as the MessageBox is closed.

What you never execute any code after this line:

```
If MsgBox("Fuel allowance ...") = MsgBoxResult.Yes
```

You code execution is this:

1. Enter textbox
2. GotFocus event is fired
3. MessageBox is shown and TextBox1.LostFocus is fired.
4. MessageBox is closed and TextBox1.GotFocus is fired.
5. MessageBox is shown and TextBox1.LostFocus is fired.
6. I think you get the picture.

I suggest you use the TextBox.Enter event instead. It is only fired once and will not be called again when you close the Messagebox.